# Can't use method return value in write context in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I'm using the below function to make sure that duplicate random ID doesn't exist in the table and make sure that duplicate random IDs doesn't exist in the table but I'm getting an error **Can't use method return value in write context in....**

```
function postex($conn)
    {
        $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM posts
                 WHERE postid = :rand');
    do {
        $random_string = generateRandomString(5);
    } while
    (
            $query->execute(array(':rand' => $random_string))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) = false

);
    return $random_string;
}
```

Is it because that something is wrong with the SQL?

Also I think this will be hard and slow process to do when more and more IDs accumulate in the table. What is the best way to make sure that duplicate random IDs doesn't exist in the table?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't use an `auto_increment` column ?

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann Well Yah I can go with that option too, I will change to that if there is no better option. I was wondering if there is a better way to look up for random queries than this function which most people suggest at stackoverflow

Comment: You want it to stop when the fetch() returns FALSE, right? Please check your while condition.

Comment: You're assigning, not comparing

Comment: @KenCheung Any idea how to make it better when looking up if a similar id exist? I think this will be cumbersome when the table increases in size isn't it?

Comment: @rksh: the solution overall is more or less fine, you are just confusing `=` and `==` operators.

Comment: You want to use a random string as ID instead of DB oriented auto field, right? Will you consider UUID / GUID instead of a random string with five(5)?? characters?

Comment: @Ken Cheung: {U,G}UID takes more space. If 5 characters is enough for a given task - no reason to inflate the database.

Comment: @zerkms the correct logic should be !== FALSE because rksh should be looking for a string NOT exist in the database as new post ID.

Comment: @Ken Cheung: I'm not insisting. My point was that comparison and assignment are different operators.

Comment: @zerkms I well 5 chars can generate a huge number of random strings with 26 letters upper and lower cases and with numbers so that is what I was thinking? Is UUID/GIUD better?

Comment: @rksh: it's not "better" but "longer". `62^5` vs `2^128` (`9e8` vs `3e38`)

Comment: @KenCheung What's the advantage over GUID/UUID than a random string with 5 chars?

Comment: When the table is EMPTY, the SELECT query always return FALSE. If we check the while( ....fetch() == FALSE) it is forever true and the loop never exit. Okay?

Comment: @rksh I think a method that targets to construct a unique string is always better than hit by random.

Comment: @Ken Cheung: "better" from what perspective?

Comment: Well, 62^5 is less than the population in China, thus it is small value in our regular consideration. As the number of records increase, P(hit) increase and the loop may need to iterate more and more, loads up DB queries and reduce system stability. With these norm in mind, a constructed unique string for use as an identifier will be better than hit by random. If you insist having random in the generation, maybe construct integer YYYYMMDDhhmmssxxxRR..R (xxx is ms, RR..R is ? digits random number) and convert it to a base 62 string.

Comment: @KenCheung well even with that the function I posted above will run many queries as the records increase and will reduce stability isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a ! in the while condition can solve the error:

```
 while
    ($query->execute(array(':rand' => $random_string))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) != false);
```